# Intel Modin Installation

Tags: python, conda, modin, intel-modin

How to install the Intel Distribution of Modin?

I want to install Intel AI Kit Modin using an existing Conda-based python environment. What are the steps required to install Modin after activating conda environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install this package with conda run one of the following:

```
conda install -c intel intel-aikit-modin

conda install -c intel/label/oneapibeta intel-aikit-modin

conda install -c intel/label/deprecated intel-aikit-modin
```