# Trouble installing intel-aikit-modin using anaconda3

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gpu, intel, xgboost, anaconda3

I have tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67278293/intel-modin-installation)  tutorial to install intel-aikit-modin using anaconda3. I ran the code as mentioned and came across this issue. [image: Error Image]

Do you have any fixes for this? I am unsure about how to proceed. I am looking at using the GPU for Jupyter Notebook to accelerate XGBoost.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There seemed to be competing files from pip install (before downloading anaconda). I uninstalled all packages and environments, reinstalled conda and downloaded all packages again which fixed the issue. There was also an error with the python version as intel-aikit-modin is only valid for python 3.7, so I had to create a virtual environment and install it there using

conda install -n <env_name> intel-aikit-modin

before doing this, ensure that intel channel has been added to conda.